# Bulk containment queries

Tags: performance, algorithm, linear-programming

I have a convex shape defined by a set of vertices. I also have a large set of points and I would like to test which are contained in the convex shape.  Currently I just use an open source linear programming solver for each point independently with a constant objective function.    See chapter 11.4 of http://www.stanford.edu/~boyd/cvxbook/bv_cvxbook.pdf for more details.

However this is quite slow even in 100 dimensions.  Is there a way to use the fact that all the query points are known in advance to speed the process up?

**edit** Fixed typo in question.

Comment: A linear programming solver? Why? Can't you just check the inequalities one by one? That should be much faster then solving an optimization problem and then throwing most of the answer away...

Comment: I would also suggest using some kind of space subdivision (a k-d tree?) You essentially break up space into parallelepipedal chunks, each of which is either (1) completely inside your shape, (2) completely outside, or (3) partly inside and crosses a *small number* of hyperplanes that define your shape. Now you only need to check a small number of one-dimensional constraints to identify which chunk your point is in, then (only if it's a type 3 chunk) a small number of N-dimensional constraints to check if it's inside your shape.

Comment: @n.m.  There was a typo. I have vertices, not inequalities.

Comment: How vertices determine a convex shape? If by their convex hull, compute the convex hull first, and now you have a set of inequalities.

Comment: Mmm, in higher dimensions computing the convex hull is probably less than trivial. What kind of goal function are you using?

Comment: @n.m. I use a constant objective function in the lp to test if the point is in the convex hull.

Comment: It might help a bit to cull the non-extreme "vertices" of your convex shape, assuming there are any.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat. How can you do that?

Comment: @oxbowlake Use the existing point-in-polytope test for each vertex in turn inside the others.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to find the convex hull of the points inside the shape.  I can't immediately think of a way to get this directly from an LP solver, but you can find the point nearest to a given hyperplane of the shape by adding a linear term for that hyperplane to the objective function.  Repeat this for all edges of the shape, and for each edge repeat it several times, eliminating the most recent solution each time to pick up increasingly distant contained points.  This should give you a number of points "close" to and inside the hyperplane.

Once you have the hull, you should then be able to classify all other points as being inside or outside it relatively quickly.  I'm sure there are algorithms to do this fairly quickly, though I'm not aware of any.  One potentially useful method that could get rid of a lot of internal points would be: if the space is n-dimensional, pick n+1 points on the hull and test every point to see whether it's a convex combination of these points (using linear algebra).

Comment: Apologies, my shape is defined by vertices. The question had an error.

Comment: The hull of n points in d dimensions can have on the order of n^(floor(d/2)) faces, and d is 100.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat: That seems to suggest that nearly all the points inside the shape will in fact lie *on* the hull.  Is that likely?  Or is the worst-case bound you mention for an unlikely pathological case?  I think the point is to establish what *proportion* of the points are on the hull vs. inside it.  If less than, say, 20% of the points are on the hull, then it may well be worthwhile trying to find the hull.

Comment: @j_random_hacker Unless the shape has barely more than d vertices (i.e., that are on the hull), I would expect iterating through the faces even in preprocessing to be a nonstarter.